# Remove deb package from repo managed by aptly

Tags: linux, apt, apt-mirror

Our organisation maintain a custom mirror for the deb package we publish. We build deb package for each project and publish it to the custom deb mirror (mentioned earlier)

Recently one of the developers created a deb package(for a project `xyz`) with wrong version we can see the wrong version  appearing on the mirror web package (index page) which appears something like this

[image: apt mirror directory listing]

We want to clean this I see he ran 3 commands to publish the package to the mirror

```
sudo aptly repo add unstable xyz_2.7.1.deb
sudo aptly snapshot create xyz2.7.1-unstable_2023-01-14 from repo unstable
sudo aptly publish -passphrase=asabc switch xenial xyz2.7.1-unstable_2023-01-14
```

Now I had manage to delete the package and snapshot using the below command

```
 sudo aptly repo remove unstable xyz_2.7.1_all
 sudo aptly snapshot drop zyz2.7.1-unstable_2023-01-14
```

But even after deleting the repo and dropping the snapshot, I still see the package appearing on the web page that I have listed above and its downloadable using HTTP client like wget , curl

Is there anything else I need to do to ensure the package is not shown on the web page?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The [aptly man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/aptly.1.html) suggests that after removing a package you should run `aptly db cleanup`.
2. I think you also need to run `aptly publish update unstable` to make the changes actually visible to apt clients.

Comment: Ran the 2 thing final command resulted in 

```ERROR: unable to update: published repo with storage:prefix/distribution ./unstable not found```

Comment: Try using whatever is the correct repo name for your situation?